# Encrypt HTTP POST upload

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a HTML form which allows users to upload a file using PHP's `$_FILES` variable.

After the file is uploaded, I do some error checking validating against the `$_FILES`, such as `$_FILES["size"]`.

Instead of calling `move_uploaded_file()` on the same page and finishing the upload. I have another HTML form which submits to a second page. The data inside `$_FILES` is passed in a POST form via the `hidden input types`.

**The problem:**

Instead of passing the values as simple text, I wish to encrypt the text (package it up) and then unpackage it back to the normal value on the next page once it has been submitted.

So far, I tried using `base64_encode` to package the content and then `base64_decode` to unpackage it, but the problem is `base64_encode` is not changing the value dynamically.

I am aware the request can be modified regardless, this is just to make it so less technical users wont be able to cheat my website

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent `$_SESSION`. PHP already gives you a place to store some state along with a user.

Comment: Session wont work too well for me in my website. if they for example upload twice in two tabs, the first one will be overriden.

Comment: It sounds like you're going about this all wrong. Re-posting the same file (to the same server?) puts you in Rube Goldberg territory. If you want to only allow one upload per user, track that fact in your DB, and disallow further uploads. Once you have the file from the user and you've checked that it's valid, why bother with the encoding/reposting?

Comment: _"I wisht to sort of encrypt the text"_ what do you mean with text? you are talking about posting a file with a form and then you switch to talk about text. Can you explain a bit more what do you mean? Maybe **if you post some code about what you have tried so far** it will be better for us to understand!

Comment: @DigitalChris Problem is, I allow uploads without the need of registering. So there is way to track if they are the valid user.

Comment: Why bother with crypt/decrypt yourself? Just use SSL.

Comment: Why not compress it with zip, tar or something of that nature? Really not sure why you're posting it back to another page. If the content needs to be secure, don't pass it back over HTTP. Keep it on the server and work with it there.

Comment: @JimmyDoe `$_SESSION` is still the right way to do this. If you want independent file uploads on two tabs, then you should still put the uploaded file in the session, under a unique key. Then, send the unique key back to the client, instead of the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that simply encoding/decoding in base64 is not "encryption" it's trivial for a client to read and/or modify that data.  It seems you're aware of this.

A better solution, if you must rely on the integrity of the data and the fact that it's been validated/sanitized, would be to digitally sign the data with a secret key on the server.

The flow would be like this:

1. User uploads file on Page 1
2. Validation happens, digital signature is computed, original data + signature is embedded in hidden field in Page 2
3. User submits Page 2, server validates signature against data.

That way, even if a technical user modifies the data, it would invalidate the signature.  It should not be possible for a user to generate a new valid signature for the modified data since they do not have the secret key.

That said, if you're going through this much trouble, why not just do the validation after the user submits Page 2?

Comment: WOW! you are actually a god send, first person to actually give a solution that is relevant for me. Cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Any ideas on how i would generate a unique 'signature'?

Comment: You could consider using [openssl_sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) or [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).  That said, is the last sentence of my answer not applicable? It is a bit wasteful to be uploading the same data twice and in any case would still be more secure.

Comment: I would not upload the same data twice. The first page uploads information about the file (size, extention etc) and the second page inserts  the choices made on the checkboxes and inserts a 'fileid' as a key for a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Would it make more sense to handle this all client side and upload in one go to avoid inconsistency? What happens if a user fills out step 1 but not step 2? Is there dangling data?  Suppose you have the user fill out step 1, you hide it all using JS and show step 2.  The user fills out step 2 and hits submit, then everything gets pushed up to the server at once.

Comment: hmm that would make sense. but the signature idea would work really nice??

Comment: Signatures is a pretty heavy handed approach to solve what sounds like a not-too-difficult problem.  Using a lot of crypto could have performance concerns if you're looking to scale this at all.